# Spring Data Project - Status?

Tags: spring-data

I am a newbie to the Spring Data component.  Why are there no recent books on "Spring Data?"  There is no "Spring Data in Action," book from Manning.com.  I bought the O'Reilly book, "Spring Data," published circa 2012.  The source code from the book download does not build in maven; it is too out of date!

I did find scattered tutorials and articles published around the web on various aspects of Spring Data.  Is there no up to date, unified treatment of the Spring Data project?  Did Spring Data flop? Go defunct?

Answer (score 3):

I can't testify to written books, but there are plenty of other material coming from the Spring Data team:

- Slides from Oliver Gierke, team leader => https://speakerdeck.com/olivergierke
- Spring Data videos from 2015: [Boot your Search with Spring](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/spring-boot-search) and [Data meets Hypermedia.](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/spring-data-rest)
- Lots of videos => http://www.infoq.com/spring_data/
- Several supported guides (including JPA, Neo4j, MongoDB, Gemfire) => https://spring.io/guides
- Less than 3 weeks since latest release of Spring Data => https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/23/spring-data-gosling-sr4-released

Given Spring Data is in competition with Spring Security as the most heavily downloaded portfolio project after Spring Boot, in short, no, it has not flopped.

I even have a dedicated chapter [in my own book](http://greglturnquist.com/category/learning-spring-boot) focused on Spring Data. As for why no one has stepped forward to write a full fledged book, well I guess those motivated to write don't overlap with those focused on Spring Data right now, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It's because it's quite a new project and it's quite simple on its own.

Further, to understand it you actually need to understand the underlying technology (such as JPA or MongoDB). Otherwise you're in for a really bad time. Also, the best way to understand it is to actually read the code, as there are plenty of surprises. For example the [`save` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/1.8.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java?av=f#428) in a JPA repository calls `persist` or `merge`... which breaks the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) (in my view).

Answer (score 0):

I think most of the activity is on the actual datasource-specific projects like `spring-data-jpa`, `spring-data-mongodb`, etc.